# Binding Selected Item on a dropdown using Knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to bind the selected value of a dropdown using knockout. The HTML is:

```
<div>
Dummy
<select id="dummy" data-bind="options: DummyOptions, optionsCaption : 'Select..', optionsText: 'Message', value: selectedValue"></select>
</div>
<button data-bind="click : setDefault">click me </button>
<div data-bind="visible: selectedValue"> <!-- Appears when you select something -->
    You have chosen a country with population
    <span data-bind="text: selectedValue() ? selectedValue().Message : 'unknown'"></span>.
```

The javascript is :

```
var dummyOptions =  ko.observableArray([{ isSelected: false, Message: "Test1" }, { isSelected: false, Message: "Test2"},{ isSelected: true, Message: "Test3"}]);

var defaultOption = ko.observable();

var vm = {
DummyOptions : dummyOptions,
selectedValue : defaultOption,
setDefault : function(){
    defaultOption = ko.observable( ko.utils.arrayFirst(dummyOptions(), function(item) {
        return item.isSelected;
    }) );   
}
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

If I try this piece of JS code without the setDefault function and setting the defaultOption variable directly, everything works fine. But, If I do it the way I have listed the code, the binding does not work.

The link to the fiddle is : http://jsfiddle.net/tNZ8f/

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setDefault` function does not update `defaultOption` but redefines it. You are creating new observable and bindings are not notified about the change. `defaultOption = new value` isn't the right way of writing new value to observable. Instead you should call observable as function with new value as parameter: `defaultOption( new value )`.

Your setDefault function should look like:

```
setDefault : function(){
    defaultOption( ko.utils.arrayFirst(dummyOptions(), function(item) {
        return item.isSelected;
    }) );   
}
```

updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tNZ8f/1/

Comment: Just another clarification... Its a bit unrelated.. How do I set the title attribute for each individual <option> item?

Comment: With `attr` binding. But you can't do this with `select` binding. To customize `<option>` tags you will have to create them with your own `foreach` loop.